# Are all unpaved roads in Tanzania unusable during rainy season?

Tags: weather-and-climate, africa, tanzania

In Tanzania, only the main trunk roads are paved and many others are unpaved. I wonder whether all unpaved roads in Tanzania are unusable during rainy season?

The official map of road network is here: [TRUNK AND REGIONAL ROADS NETWORK](https://www.tanroads.go.tz/uploads/files/Trunk_and_Regional_Road_Map.pdf)

Comment: It may depend on the vehicle too. The answer to the very broad question is probably No.

Comment: I have friends who live in the Tanzania/Kenya/Uganda area, they have a Land Rover and have no problems.